# show updated textview inside a child Activity after using AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am using Tabhost, inside the first Tab ( Clients ), i have a Parent Activity(which contains a listview), when i click an item from that Listview, a child Activity will replace the Parent one, inside the same Tab ("Clients" from Tabhost), ok "don't fall asleep :)"
in this child Activity, i have a TextView and a button, when that button is clicked, an AlertDialog show up to put a number.

Finally, "the problem is here now", when i put a number and confirm with that AlertDialog, i want that my Textview shows the Number Instantly, but it doesn't happen :'(

But when i go back to ParentActivity, then return again to child one, i found my updated TextView with then entered Number...

I hope, you guys understand me ( plz GOD it was too long :) ).
-Edit-
**This is the 1st class :**

```
public class Group_Clients extends ABCGroup{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("Gestion_Clients", new Intent(this,Gestion_Clients.class));
}
```

}

**This is the 2nd Class (contains the Listview) :**

```
public class Gestion_Clients extends Activity{

BDD_Manage Bdd = new BDD_Manage(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1_clients);

    ImageButton btn_addClient = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.client_add);
    ImageButton btn_subClient = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.client_delete);
    ImageButton btn_editClient = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.client_edit);
    ImageButton btn_chercher = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.client_search);
    ImageButton btn_actualiser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.client_refresh);

    showListview();

    btn_addClient.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), Clients_ajout.class);
            ABCGroup parentActivity = (ABCGroup)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Clients_ajout", edit);
        }
    });     

    btn_actualiser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Actualiser !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onResume();
        }
    });

final ListView clientsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_clients);
clientsList.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

clientsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long idClient) {
        Bdd.open();
        Bdd.putclientID((int) idClient);
        Bdd.close();

        Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), Client_detaille.class);
        ABCGroup parentActivity = (ABCGroup)getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("Client_detaille", edit);
    }
});
}
```

**This is the 3rd Class (contains buttons and where Alertdialog is showed) :**

```
public class Client_detaille extends Activity{

TextView tv_Nom, tv_colonnes, tv_infos, tv_avc, tv_datemodif, List_code, List_conduit, List_Examcode, List_Examconduit;
EditText S_code, S_conduit;
ImageButton addAvc, delAvc, addCode, delCode, addConduit, delConduit, addEXcode, delEXcode, delEXconduit, addEXconduit;
BDD_Manage bdd = new BDD_Manage(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client_details);

    addAvc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_avance);
    delAvc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.del_avance);
    addCode = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus01);
    delCode = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus01);
    addConduit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus02);
    delConduit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus02);

    showInfos();

  //...... Config action of Button -Add Meeting- ......        
    addCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertBox(1, 1);
            onResume();
        }
    });
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~Display Client Infos~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showInfos(){
    String nom, prn, dn, nat, profs, adr, tel1, tel2, dateModif, avc="", payed="", notPayed="", scodes="", sconduits="", EXcodes="", EXconduits="";
    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontastique.ttf");
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/small.ttf");

    tv_Nom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tv_colonnes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_left);
    tv_infos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_right);
    tv_avc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_avance);
    tv_datemodif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_datemodif);
    List_code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Scode001);
    List_conduit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sconduit001);
    List_Examcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Examcode001);
    List_Examconduit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExamConduit001);

    bdd.open();
    Cursor cur = bdd.getdataFrom("Clients", bdd.getclientID());
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    nom   = cur.getString(1);      prn    = cur.getString(2);      dn         = cur.getString(3);    nat   = cur.getString(4);
    profs = cur.getString(5);      adr    = cur.getString(6);      tel1       = cur.getString(7);    tel2  = cur.getString(8);
    dateModif = cur.getString(9);  payed  = cur.getString(10);     notPayed   = cur.getString(11);   avc   = cur.getString(12);
    scodes= cur.getString(13);     sconduits = cur.getString(14);  EXcodes    = cur.getString(15);   EXconduits = cur.getString(16);

    tv_Nom.setTypeface(font1);
    tv_colonnes.setTypeface(font1);
    tv_infos.setTypeface(font1);
    tv_avc.setTypeface(font1);
    tv_datemodif.setTypeface(font2);
    List_code.setTypeface(font1);
    List_conduit.setTypeface(font1);
    List_Examcode.setTypeface(font1);
    List_Examconduit.setTypeface(font1);

    tv_Nom.setText(nom+" "+prn);
    //---------------------------
    tv_colonnes.setText(Html.fromHtml("Date naissance :<br>Nationalité :<br>Profession :<br>Adresse :<br>" +
            "Tel1 :<br>Tel2 :<br><font color='lime'>Payé : "+payed));
    //---------------------------
    tv_infos.setText(Html.fromHtml(dn+"<br>"+nat+"<br>"+profs+"<br>"+adr+
            "<br>"+tel1+"<br>"+tel2+"<br><font color='red'>A Payé : "+notPayed));
    //---------------------------
    if(avc!=null)
        tv_avc.setText(avc+" Dt");
    //---------------------------
    tv_datemodif.setText("modifié le: "+dateModif);
    //---------------------------
    if(scodes!=null && !scodes.equals(""))
        List_code.setText(scodes);
    //---------------------------
    if(sconduits!=null)
        List_conduit.setText(sconduits);
    //---------------------------
    if(EXcodes!=null)
        List_Examcode.setText(EXcodes);
    //---------------------------
    if(EXconduits!=null)
        List_Examconduit.setText(EXconduits);

    bdd.close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe post some code?

Comment: This video can explain more my problem, please wathc this video, and help me plz !! i need this task to be accomplished !!
http://www.mediafire.com/watch/kwo811dwjw06d81/Capture-Android.mp4

as you can see, when i add a line to my database, and want this one to be displayed (with old data from database), it wouldn't, but when i go back then return to the target interface, i found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself :)

i had just to update my view (all textview(s) and other...) before i show the AlertDialog.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getParent());
final View alertDialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.ajout_seance_code, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder adbx = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
    adbx.setView(alertDialog);
    if(x==1){
        adbx.setTitle("Séance Code ++");
    }else{adbx.setTitle("Séance Conduit ++");}

    //On affecte un bouton "OK" à notre AlertDialog et on lui affecte un évènement
    adbx.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            BDD_Manage BdD = new BDD_Manage(getApplicationContext());
            String date, nbrH, prix, ligne="";
            EditText et_date, et_nbrH, et_prix;
            boolean res=true;
            int pr=0;
            BdD.open();
            .
            .etc
            .// and before showing the AlertDialog ( Alertdialog.show() ), i need here to update Textviex(s) values, so that way new datas are displayed instantly.
            showInfos();
            BdD.close();
        }
    });
    adbx.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `static` method in you `MainActivity` that take the new input value to set the `TextVeiw` and call this method on destroying you CustomDialog as following:

```
public static void setUpdatedData(String value){
    textView.setText(value);
    textview.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: then how to use this method in the child Activity ??? when Alertdialog finished ?

Comment: If you are creating positive and negative buttons, then when you are implementing their `onClickListener` call this method at the end of your code

Comment: didn't work :Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity

Comment: You only St The value in this method, don't Initialize the view in the static method

Comment: Can you please look at my code ??
Because, i gaved just an exemple ( about a TextView ), but my real problem, is initialize many TextViews with Data from my Database.
so i tryed to put my method "showinfos()", in this static method, but i couldn't.

Comment: What is the exact problem now?

Comment: look at this and you will understand :)
http://www.mediafire.com/watch/vmv6kpe3r160sfl/Capture.mp4
See those informations about a Client ?? they are all stored then, showed to/from my Database.